# Mongoose schema async method doesn't wait

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

this is my code :

```
const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');
console.log(' user value : ', user);
const boolean = await user.comparePassword(password, user.password);
console.log('boolean value  : ', boolean);
```

The results of my flags in console :

```
user value :  {
  role: 'user',
  passwordChangedAt: 2021-04-14T02:19:54.689Z,
  _id: 6074b03b28f33810a528d61f,
  name: 'Javier',
  password: '$2a$12$cSsURwyoGGd2j9kreuwnGur3pYaTmnY3K2vjXRSJpDhptDwy0t4lG',
  __v: 0
}
boolean value :  undefined
```

So, boolean var is not waiting, and i don't know why. These is my function in my userschema :

````
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = catchAsync(async function comparePassword(
  password,
  userPassword
) {
  const aux = await bcrypt.compare(password, userPassword);
  return aux;
});
```

How can i force boolean to wait for the result of comparePassword function ?
````

Comment: What is `catchAsync`? Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67085134/edit) your question to include it as well? If I had to guess, it probably doesn't return the return value of the function passed to it.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem i've allready fix it removing the catchAsync, ```module.exports = (fn) => (req, res, next) => {
  fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
};```  the function wraps the asyncs functions and catch the errors, to avoid try catch blocks.

Comment: Try `userSchema.methods.comparePassword =  bcrypt.compare(password, userPassword);`. You are then awaiting it anyway, no need to add `await` a second time here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async (password, userPassword) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.compare(password, userPassword, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                resolve(false);
            }
            if (result == true) {
                resolve(true);
            } else {
                resolve(false);
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `(err,result) => { if(err) reject() else resolve(result); }`. Also, according to [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt), `await bcrypt.compare()` is perfectly valid, why did you wrap it in a Promise? This is just adding unnecessary complexity